# Control Access To Azure SQL Server Admin Password Reset In Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-rbac

Is it possible thru RBAC (Role Based Access) to control who can use the reset password feature on the an Azure SQL Server in the Azure Portal

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to Control Password Reset on Azure SQL DB**.

I have assigned **Reader Role** on **Azure SQL DB** as below.

**Open Azure SQL DB > Access control (IAM) > Add > Add Role Assignment > Reader.**

[image]

When I try to reset the password with the same user, getting the below error.

[image]

Assigned **contributer** role to the group for managing **Azure SQL DB**

Created a group and assigned members to the group as below.

[image]

**Role Assignment to group**

[image]

Now I'm able to reset the **Azure SQL DB** password as below.

> Whoever is part of the group can be able to reset the **Azure SQL DB** password.

[image]